# Why this code be terminated?

Tags: objective-c

I has written following code and then run.
In after, When I touch uibutton, this app is terminated.

I want to know why terminated.

I doubt if autorelease?

Are there anyone who can explicitly explain

why myClass instance is released and

where myClass is released and

the way that myClass can use autorelease?

```
    @interface MyClass : NSObject
    - (void)testMethod;
    @end

    @implementation MyClass{
        NSMutableArray *array;
    }

    - (id)init{
        if ((self = [super init])) {
            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)dealloc {
        [array release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (void)testMethod {
        NSLog(@"after init : %@", array);
    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController {
        MyClass *myClass;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];  <== cause of ternimate?

        UIButton *aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testArray:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        aButton.frame=CGRectMake(110.0f, 129.0f, 100.0f, 57.0f);
        [aButton setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];
        [self.view addSubview:aButton];

    }

    - (void)testArray:(id)sender {
        [myClass testMethod];
    }
@end
```

Comment: This is definitely **not** a reason why your program terminates, but you should change `UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected` to use `OR`s instead of `AND`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that due to

```
myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

the instance of MyClass is already deallocated when you touch the button. Don't be lazy - autorelease is *not* an ultimate 'solve my memory management problem and make me not have to think' solution - here you need to use just

```
myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

then release it manually when needed - probably in your ViewController class' -dealloc method.

Comment: Why does myClass deallocate?  myClass instance is met the @autoreleasepool of main.m?

Comment: @user1182731 unknown reason - that's implementation defined, probably it's deallocated when the scope of viewDidLoad exits. (Only if you read the docs... UIApplicationMain never returns, so it can't at all hit the main autorelease pool...)

Answer (score 1):

```
myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Probably because you're autoreleasing `myClass`. It's an instance variable, so it should be retained (and then released in the class's `dealloc` method).

Comment: Is it impossible to use the autorelease in custom class like MyClass?

Comment: The autorelease can be used in what cases?

Comment: As it is an autoreleased object, you cannot predict when it will be released. Ideally the member variables should not be autoreleased, as we will be refering to them in other parts of the code. So it is better to havve a retain property for the member variable.

Comment: If you need to create some objects for temporary purpose, that you wont be needing anymore. In that case you can use autorelease.

Answer (score 0):

It is the autorelease that is causing an issue.

You should make myClass a property.

```
@implementation ViewController {

    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass *myClass;

    @synthesize myClass
    -(void)dealloc
    {
      [myClass release];
      [super dealloc];
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];

        UIButton *aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testArray:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        aButton.frame=CGRectMake(110.0f, 129.0f, 100.0f, 57.0f);
        [aButton setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];
        [self.view addSubview:aButton];

    }

    - (void)testArray:(id)sender {
        [myClass testMethod];
    }
```